# How to get a list of doc name from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array:

```
dataset_tr = 'data/20news_clean/train.txt.npy'
data_tr = np.load(dataset_tr)
```

the`data_tr` looks like this: It is a 3*10 numpy array:

```
[array([ 700,  152,  572,  572,  619,  724,  326, 1571,  572,   99])
 array([ 331,  152,  397, 1273,   89,  228,  0,    0,    0,      0])
 array([   6,    1,   26,  174,  216,  135, 1060,  259,   75,    7])]
```

Each row here is a representation for a document in the `20newsgroup` dataset.

All I want to do is to create a key out of this 2d array. The result will be `1 * 3` because I had 3 row in my 2d aaray.

Actually what I am doing here is that I am trying to assign a name to each row of that array. So the result will look like this:

```
['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3']
```

I am able to get this but by looping through the 2d array.

Is there any better numpy way of doing this?

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you provide a sample of `data_tr` and the working code with the loop?

Comment: @Ivan I have already provided how my input looks like `data_tr` which is a `npy` numpy array, and the output is going to assign a name to each row of that 2d numpy. Here is a 3*10 so thats why I get an array of 1*3 name. Ill try to add more content to my question

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for your input. I just made some update I hope my question is more clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired result with a list comprehension:

```
result = ['doc%i' % i for i in range(len(data_tr))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
docs = ['doc'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(data_tr)]
```